# Collection View in a Table View not recognize all sections

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Collection View inside the Table View. My table view has 5 sections in this moment, but the collection view only actives three times this function:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
```

and the table view actives five times this function:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

Why could this be?

If you need examples, ask for them.

Comment: I think you might need to explain this in a different way as its not clear what your asking.  you have 5 sections in your tableview, and each cell has a collection view? and what is the problem that your running into?

Comment: hi yes, i have 5 sections in my tableview and each cell has a collection view. In the first 3 sections the collection view loads fine, loads numberOfItemsInSection, loads collectionViewLayout and loads cellForItemAtIndexPath. But the last two do not load those functions; it is like they do not exist. What the system does is to repeat the first two in the last two.

Comment: Another example is seen in the function numberOfItemsInSection. I set a tag for each collection view. However, the system only sets tags for three collectionview; the others two are not set.

Comment: The tableview is only going to load the cells that are visible so if the first 3 are the only ones visible then thats all it will load.  If you scroll does it load the next few?  Is this what your experiencing?

Comment: When I scroll, the tableview loads the other cells, but not the collection view.